# Не видно созданной папки в диспетчере файлов

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk

Предполагаю что дело в кеше.
При сохранении изображения с создаю папку Folder и сохраняю туда картинку.
Директория: ./sdcard/Pictures/Folder/image.jpg
Вот сам код

```
public void fileImageSave(Bitmap bitmap) {

    File path = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            Constants.FOLDER_SAVE_WALL);

    if( ! path.exists()) path.mkdirs();

    Random generator = new Random();
    String name = generator.nextInt(10000) + ".jpg";

    File file = new File(path, name);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();

    try {

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

        imageResizeDisplay(bitmap).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();

        Toast.makeText(context,
                context.getString(R.string.toast_saved).replace("#", Constants.FOLDER_SAVE_WALL), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.toast_saved_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Папка создается и картинка сохраняется, но в диспетчере ее можно найти только если перейти в раздел "Внутренний накопитель" и найти созданную папку. С главной диспетчера перейдя в категорию Фото, этой папки нет пока не перезагрузишь устройство. Дело в кеше? Что необходимо предпринять?

Answer (score 1):

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { file.getPath() }, null, null);
```